# Content tagging/bookmarking by users

Tags: ios, database, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` that is populated with content that can be tagged/bookmarked by a user. My app successfully sends the bookmark info to a server-side database when content is bookmarked. I'm trying to figure the most efficient way to display a bookmarked image in the respective cell if the content has already been bookmarked by the user.

For example, a user taps a cell's bookmark and the bookmark image displays a different image to verify the bookmark. The bookmark info is sent to the database. *This already works*

Here's where I need help...

When the user opens the app again, the `UITableView` is re-populated with data. If the cell contains content that has been bookmarked, I need to display the bookmarked image in the cell. Right now, I have a database query in `ViewDidLoad` that pulls the user's bookmarks. The only implementation I can think of is searching through the query data in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. However, I know this is going to affect my scrolling performance. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have millions of bookmarks, then checking the bookmark flag on each `cellForRowAtIndexPath` should not impact the performance much.

In my experience table view scrolling is very very efficient, and there is still plenty of processor time to do other things. Doing a simple check for a value at an index shouldn't affect it much. Perhaps the best way to approach it, would be to parse your query result and create a dedicated NSArray with ONLY the YES/NO flag at each respective index, that you can check during `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to make a decision whether you show the bookmarked indicator or not.

If you really need to gain as much speed as possible, you could create a C array `viewDidLoad`  with 0/1 values at each specific index and access it `array[index]`. This removes ANY additional overhead that could be there in NSArray. But again - my experience shows that for these kinds of uses, the overhead is minimal.